# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS in kali linux

Tags: java, linux

Each time i execute java code i get this message:
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

[image]
This problem has solution for windows os but i can't find any solution for linux os.

Comment: Please add the text of the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not warning, it is information.

It literally says that some settings were picked up from `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environmental variable. It is used to configure some switches "globally" for every java application that will be run in given environment. You must have this set either on system or user level. If you remove that variable, information will be gone.

Comment: ok i dont want this message to print each and every time i execute how can i do that ?? specially in kali linux

Comment: Like i wrote, unset `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environmental variable

Comment: thanks a lot but i think u can make your answer more clear if u just add this line : unset _JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: That is literally the last sentence from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Java Option disabling in terminal

if your using java11-jdk in linux this might be working for disabling the java option from displaying in terminal.

```
_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS" && unset _JAVA_OPTIONS &&  alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

[image: Checkout the Screenshot Here]

Answer (score 2):

**ON Kali Linux ANDROID STUDIO**
This information comes because an environment variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS setup by default. I solved it by Unseating the variable.
**To unset the value of this variable, *use unset _JAVA_OPTIONS*.

After that Android Studio will no longer display the information and Android Studio will be able to build projects that were previously failing to build..